# Entremezclar 2 arreglos e imprimirlos en java

Tags: java, array, bucle-for

Estoy tratando de hacer un codigo en java que entremezcle 2 arrays pero hasta ahora no logro que funcione, también me gustaría saber como podría hacer para que al rellenar un array no me muestre los números uno por uno al insertarlos, sino que se muestre el array completo con todos los numeros recién al finalizar el bucle. Agradezco su ayuda de antemano.

```
package arreglosejercicio3;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArreglosEjercicio3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a[], b[], c[], incremento = 0;

    Scanner array = new Scanner(System.in);

    a = new int[10];
    b = new int[10];
    c = new int[20];

    System.out.println("Por favor inserte los numeros del array:" + "\n");

    System.out.println("Inserte los elementos de a:");

    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {

    a[i] = array.nextInt();

        System.out.println("El arreglo a es: " + a[i]);

}
    System.out.println("Inserte los elementos de b: ");

    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {

    b[i] = array.nextInt();

        System.out.println("El arreglo b es: " + b[i]);

}

    for(int i= 0; i<20; i++) {

     c[incremento] = a[i];

     incremento ++;

     c[incremento] = b[i];

     incremento++;

     System.out.println("El arreglo es: " + c[i]);

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar que al rellenar un `array` no muestre los números uno por uno, debes quitar `System.out.println()` del `for` que utilizas para insertar los valores en el `array`.

Haz un recorrido para introducir valores y otro para visualizar el contenido del array:

```
//Insertar elementos en el array
System.out.println("Inserte los elementos de a:");  
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    a[i] = array.nextInt();
}

//Visualizar el array  
System.out.print("El arreglo a es: "); 
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
}
```

Después para entremezclar los dos `arrays` en uno, he realizado un `for`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    c[incremento] = a[i];
    incremento++;
    c[incremento] = b[i];
    incremento++;
}
```

Por último, un bucle para mostrar los valores entremezclado en el `array c`:

```
System.out.println("\nEl arreglo resultante es: ");     
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

    System.out.println(c[i]+" ");
}
```

**Código completo del ejercicio:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArreglosEjercicio3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a[], b[], c[], incremento = 0;

        Scanner array = new Scanner(System.in);

        a = new int[10];
        b = new int[10];
        c = new int[20];

        System.out.println("Por favor inserte los numeros del array:" + "\n");

        System.out.println("Inserte los elementos de a:");  
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            a[i] = array.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.print("El arreglo a es: "); 
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
        }

        System.out.println("\nInserte los elementos de b: ");   
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            b[i] = array.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.print("El arreglo b es: "); 
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print(b[i]+" ");
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            c[incremento] = a[i];
            incremento++;
            c[incremento] = b[i];
            incremento++;
        }

        System.out.println("\nEl arreglo resultante es: ");     
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

            System.out.println(c[i]+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

prueba a ver si te funciona

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
```

Comment: No logro hacer que funcione, pero gracias igual por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Primero sobre el error, al hacer esto `for(int i= 0; i<20; i++)` lo que haces es intentar recorrer 20 espacios en los arreglos a y b, que solo tienen 10 espacios. Para resolverlo necesitas `for(int i= 0; i<10; i++)`

Segundo, para que no te muestre los números que vas ingresando necesitas quitar la impresión `System.out.println("El arreglo b es: " + b[i]);` que están dentro de los `for`

Por último, sobre mostrar todos los elementos del arreglo después de haber introducido sus datos necesitas volver a recorrerlo con algo así:

```
for (int i: c) {
        System.out.println("El arreglo es: " + i);
    }
```

lo que es equivalente a

```
for(int i= 0; i<10; i++) {
     System.out.println("El arreglo es: " + c[i]);
}
```